# What is the correct way to phrase this

Tags: phrase-requests

Which is correct way to say:

- We request the account to be closed.
- we request the account is closed.

Comment: You could completely avoid the issue of whether or not to use the subjunctive with: "We request that you close the account."

Comment: If you want to maintain the *passive voice*, you can say, We request that the account be closed, as is suggested in the answer. I think it is the *passive voice* with which you're struggling, so it might be helpful for you to read up on it.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably go with something like:

> We request that the account be closed.